# Android Studio and JavaFx

Tags: android, for-loop, javafx

Hi im Java\JavaFx\Android-Studio beginner

i wrote a little app in JavaFx, it works fine, now i try to run it on a Smartphone with Android Studio.

Most of this code Works, but i have a problem with my for Loop, it doesnt work, and i dont know why :(

The foundWords List remains empty...
But on my Source Projekt in JavaFx it still works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String word;
String list;
char[] wordChars;
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();


EditText input;
TextView output;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);

}


/*
Read Textfile
*/
public void readTextfile() {
    BufferedReader read = null;
    try {
        read = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("test.txt")));


        Arrays.asList(wordList);

        while ((list = read.readLine()) != null) {
            wordList.add(list);
        }
        read.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    Log.i("ListRead", "Done"); }

public static int getNumValue(char[] string, char val) {
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : string) {
        if (c == val) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static boolean notTooManyLetters(char[] word, char[] wordChars) {
    for (char letter : wordChars) {
        if (getNumValue(word, letter) > getNumValue(wordChars, letter)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static boolean sameLetters(char[] w, char[] wordChars) {
    for (char letter : w) {
        if (new String(wordChars).indexOf(letter) < 0) {
            return false;

        }

    }
    return true;
}

// Create Result
public void compare() {

    List<String> foundWords = new ArrayList<String>();
    word = input.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
    wordChars = word.toCharArray();

    for (String w : wordList) {
        for (char letter : wordChars) {
            if (word.indexOf(letter) > 0 && foundWords.indexOf(w) < 0 && w.length() <= wordChars.length
                    && notTooManyLetters(w.toCharArray(), wordChars) && sameLetters(w.toCharArray(), wordChars)) {
                foundWords.add(w);
            } else {
                if (foundWords.size() <= 0) {
                    Log.i("CheckList", "Empty List!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    output.setText(foundWords.toString());
}

public void onKlickAbc(View view) {
    readTextfile();
    compare();


}}
```

Comment: Check with System.out this part .. `if (word.indexOf(letter) > 0 && foundWords.indexOf(w) < 0 && w.length() <= wordChars.length
                    && notTooManyLetters(w.toCharArray(), wordChars) && sameLetters(w.toCharArray(), wordChars)) {
                foundWords.add(w);
            }` So you can better understand what your code is doing and why this if statement is never true..

Comment: As far as I can tell (I've never developed JavaFX applications for Android) this isn't a JavaFX question. There is certainly no JavaFX code posted.

Comment: Addet the JavaFx code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code simply never executes.

Your activity overrides lifecycle methods and those are the only methods the OS is going to call. Any other methods are useless if not linked or triggered from these lifecycle methods.

Indeed, in Android you don't have access to a "main loop" like in other UI frameworks. Please refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities#mtal

PS: welcome to SO :)

Comment: Ty, but can u tell me or give me a example how to slove my Problem?